# this.style.display = none; issue in Google Chrome - HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, styles

When I use this line:

```
<div id="page1" onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="keks.style.display = 'block'" style="color: grey;">
    <p></p><h1>You want a cookie?</h1><p></p><br>
    <img id="keks" src="http://www.versuchschemie.de/upload/files2/30837447_420.jpg" style="display: none; margin: auto;" onclick="{page1.style.display = 'none'; page2.style.display = 'block'}">
</div>
```

And click on it in Google Chrome, nothing happens. Just the font-color is changing.
In Mozilla Firefox at School, it works like a charme.

Comment: first of all i dont know what keks is, and second i only see that you change the font color, style.display=block can cause no reaction if display was block before.

Comment: Element IDs do not become global variables. You need to use `document.getElementById('keks')`

Comment: Barmar: they do http://jsfiddle.net/yjs6U/

Comment: @user359374 - next time, please, reformat the code so that no horizontal scrolling is needed, as it is unhelpful. @Barmar - they do become global variables, unfortunately, but this practice is discouraged and should not be used. Also, inline event listeners is another bad practice and should be replaced with `addEventListener` (and `attachEvent`, if you support Internet Explorer 8 and earlier) in an external script. Also, the curly braces within the `onclick` attribute of `<img>` are a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

`onclick="keks.style.display"`

should be

`onclick="document.getElementById('keks').style.display"`

Comment: Since you are suggesting not to use a global var, you've got my upvote. Out of curiosity: Shouldn't the keks thing work to? What I find interesting is that in the click handler the other element 'page1' is actually there, but keks is not. (It's placed beneath the clicked element, but I think that shouldn't matter at the time the click is made) Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kK5Y5/ Click the headline: page1 is there, keks is undefined. Why?

Comment: @Robin Try switching the IDs of the `div` and `img`, then 'keks' will be defined but 'page1' will be undefined, I'm not exactly sure why

Comment: @Robin I reproduced it here http://jsfiddle.net/GF6ME/1/ and its working for `div` and `p` tags but not `img`, someone with more experience should answer that question because i have no idea why